Logstash, how to keep entire php log message in message field?
I used logstash gelf plugin from port_udp to collect php log, if there is ['id' => $id] like structure in log, the key value pair will become a separate field ctxt_id in logstash and make meesage field not complete like below shows.
php log example:

$id = 1;
$logger->info('Got a new id', ['id' => $id]);

log in logstash example:

2024-09-09 10:47:54 {
2024-09-09 10:47:54     "release_timestamp" => "n/a",
2024-09-09 10:47:54              "pod_name" => "n/a",
2024-09-09 10:47:54               "message" => "Got a new id",
2024-09-09 10:47:54              "@version" => "1",
2024-09-09 10:47:54             "ctxt_id" => 1,
...

How to avoid generating a new field "ctxt_id" automatically but keep entire and original log message information in message field?
